# How does one define a PECL bbcode extension callback when writing a CodeIgniter library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback, bbcode, pecl

I'm writing a CodeIgniter library around PHP's `bbcode` PECL extension, but I'm having some trouble with callbacks.

I set up the handler in the library constructor:

```
function __construct() {

    $basic = array(
        'url' => array(
            'type' => BBCODE_TYPE_OPTARG,
            'open_tag' => '<a href="{PARAM}" rel="nofollow">',
            'close_tag' => '</a>',
            'childs'=>'i,b,u,strike,center,img',
            'param_handling' => array($this, 'url')
            )
    );
    $this->handler = bbcode_create($basic); 
}

public function parse($bbcode_string) {
    return bbcode_parse($this->handler, htmlentities($bbcode_string));
}
```

As you notice, this uses a callback for handling what's allowed to go into the URL. I use this to insert an "exit redirect" page

```
public static function url($content, $argument) {
    if (!$argument) $argument = $content;
    $url = parse_url($argument);

    if (!isset($url['host'])) {
        if (strlen($argument) > 0 && $argument[0] != '/') return false;
        $destination = '//'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$argument;
    } elseif ($url['host'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
        $destination = '//'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/exit?'.urlencode($argument);
    } else {
        $destination = $argument;
    }

    return htmlspecialchars($destination);
}
```

And I also have a little function which helps me test this out as I work:

```
function test() {
    $string = '[url]http://www.google.com[/url]';
    echo '<pre>';
    die($this->parse($string));
}
```

This all works fine **if the `test()` method is called from within the library**. For example, if I throw `$this->test()` at the bottom of the constructor, everything works exactly as I would expect. However, calling `$this->bbcode->test()` from somewhere else (e.g. in a controller), I get the following errors:

```
**A PHP Error was encountered**
Severity: Warning
Message:  Invalid callback , no array or string given
Filename: libraries/bbcode.php
Line Number: 122

**A PHP Error was encountered**
Severity: Warning
Message:  bbcode_parse(): function `' is not callable
Filename: libraries/bbcode.php
Line Number: 122

<a href="" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com</a>
```

The callback does not get executed, and as a result the link's `href` attribute is empty. Line 122 refers to the single line of code in my `parse` function:

```
return bbcode_parse($this->handler, htmlentities($bbcode_string));
```

How do I address this callback function such that it can be located when `$this->bbcode->test()` is called from inside a controller?

---

**Now I'm even more confused...**

So in the hopes of just putting this all behind me, I put these callback functions in a helper so I can just call them directly. So I now have code like this:

```
function __construct() {

    $basic = array(
        'url' => array(
            'type' => BBCODE_TYPE_OPTARG,
            'open_tag' => '<a href="{PARAM}" rel="nofollow">',
            'close_tag' => '</a>',
            'childs'=>'i,b,u,strike,center,img',
            'param_handling' => 'bbcode_url'
            )
    );
    $this->handler = bbcode_create($basic);   
}
```

With the above, I get the following error:

```
**A PHP Error was encountered**
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid callback 6.7949295043945E-5, no array or string given
Filename: libraries/bbcode.php
Line Number: 176

**A PHP Error was encountered**
Severity: Warning
Message: bbcode_parse(): function `6.7949295043945E-5' is not callable
Filename: libraries/bbcode.php
Line Number: 176
```

(line 176 is the new location of the `parse()` function)

Um... I don't even know what's going on. The number `6.7949295043945E-5` changes with every attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found to this is quite simply not to set the handler up in a constructor. Instead, the `parse()` method contains *both* the `bbcode_create()` call and the `bbcode_parse()` call. That is, the `bbcode_handler` is freshly created for every string of bbcode to be parsed.

This seems needlessly wasteful to me. But, over the course of the lifetime of this project, it is exceedingly unlikely to cost even a tenth of the amount of time that I have spent trying to sort this out "properly", so I'm calling it a day.

I'm posting this "solution" here in case somebody else happens across this question and can thereby save themselves a few hours' pain. That said, I would really like to know what on earth is going on, and how to do this properly.